# How do I undo user input in a SAPUI5 fragment

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 xml fragment with an input bound a model...

```
<Input value="{tableData>orderAcknowledgment}" maxLength="20" />
```

How do implement an 'Undo' button, so that any changes are ignored?

I've tried .reftesh(true), .updateBindings(true), and .resetChanges() also, tried .resetChanges(path).

Comment: So you mean resetting the input to initial empty value, not "undo", right?

Comment: And which ODataModel exactly is involved? V2 or V4?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the new values you need to set a different binding for the model, try something like this:

```
"sap/ui/model/BindingMode"

tableData.setDefaultBindingMode(BindingMode.OneWay);
```

Changed values of the input aren't going to have an effect on the original model value